# Jquery $ is undefined with requirejs using shim

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm getting issues with jQuery not being found when trying to add addons/plugins

```
TypeError: $ is undefined
$.fn.sketch = function () {
```

I have the following project layout in ASP.net

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/VideoApp/")%>app" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/VideoApp/app/require.js") %>"></script>
```

file structure

- /Scripts

  - /VideoApp
  - app.js

    - /app

      - require.js
    - /lib

      - jquery-1.9.1.min.js
      - Sketch.js
      - spectrum.js
      - domReady.js

app.js

```
require.config({
    "baseUrl": "/Scripts/VideoApp/lib",
    "paths": {
        "jquery": 'jquery-1.9.1.min',
        "app": "../app"
    },
    shim: {
        "spectrum": {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'spectrum'
        },
        "Sketch": {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'sketch'
        }
    }
});

require(['domReady'], function (domReady) {
    domReady(function () {
        require(['jquery', 'spectrum', 'Sketch'], function ($) {

            $('#videoSketch').sketch();
        });
    });
});
```

i'm not getting any 404 errors file not found, it seems jQuery isn't loaded, i've tried changing  `"jquery": 'jquery-1.9.1.min'` to google hosted library as such
`"jquery": '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min` with no success.

If anyone has a idea of what i've setup incorrectly would appreciate the feedback!

Comment: It most likely needs to be included higher in your include precedence. If any of your scripts use jquery, you'll need to load jquery first.

Comment: my understanding is requiredjs loads script files asynchronously prior to them being required.

`"jquery": 'jquery-1.9.1.min'` defines where to find jquery and the `shim` definition defines that `jquery` needs to be loaded prior to loading sketch.js or spectrum.js  

If you have more information on how I should be fixing the precedence taking into account i'm using the _requiredjs_ library i'd highly appreciate it!

Comment: Two additional points - 1) your project includes require.js but you indicate that your require.config/shim info is in app.js...does your require.js call/reference app.js? 2) I believe you're missing quotes around your `shim` (should be `"shim"`).

Comment: Appreciate it @ethorn10
Tried amending the _"shim"_ property name although same issue. The documentation seems to use either strings or names interchangeably

The documentation says to call _require.js_ with _app.js_ as the `data-main` property on the `<script>` tag. Its definitely loading it correctly as I can execute code from _app.js_

Comment: @ethorn10 There's absolutely no need to quote `shim`.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a fiddle?